# Troubles with exceptions in Pyowm api

Tags: python, api

I am working at the very primitive script on Python that giving current wheather info in the console. So all is ok but if I typing wrong city's name (Nev Uork, for example), there is an exception appears in the console.

API - [pyowm](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dismay\Documents\Python\WeatherHelper2.py", line 28, in <module>
main = owm.weather_at_place(place)
File "C:\Users\Dismay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\webapi25\owm25.py", line 210, in weather_at_place
_, json_data = self._wapi.cacheable_get_json(uri, params=params)
File "C:\Users\Dismay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 44, in cacheable_get_json
status_code, data = self.get_json(uri, params=params, headers=headers)
File "C:\Users\Dismay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 31, in get_json
HttpClient.check_status_code(resp.status_code, resp.text)
File "C:\Users\Dismay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 112, in check_status_code
raise api_response_error.NotFoundError('Unable to find the resource')
pyowm.exceptions.api_response_error.NotFoundError: The searched item was not found.
Reason: Unable to find the resource
```

**And I wanna catch this exception and print something like that:**

```
try:
owm.weather_at_place(place)
except (pyowm.exceptions.api_response_error.NotFoundError):
print("Wrong information, try again and find out mistakes please")
time.sleep(10)
```

**I was trying to do it so much times but always it was failed. Do you know how to work with api's exceptons correctly?**

Thanks for attention!
Below is the full code.

```
import pyowm
import time 
from colorama import * 
from pyowm.exceptions import *

init(autoreset = True)

print(Fore.BLACK + Back.WHITE + 'Let`s go')



owm = pyowm.OWM('bbc3649126d17d7bb4111c44c6a562d5')
place = input("Place you find: ")

main = owm.weather_at_place(place)
weather = main.get_weather()
maxtemp = weather.get_temperature("celsius")["temp_max"] 
midtemp =  weather.get_temperature("celsius")["temp"]
mintemp = weather.get_temperature("celsius")["temp_min"]
speedwind = weather.get_wind()["speed"]
status = weather.get_detailed_status()
azimuth = weather.get_wind()["deg"]
humidity = weather.get_humidity()

try:
    owm.weather_at_place(place)
except (urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError, 
api_response_error.NotFoundError('Unable to find the resource')):
print("""Wrong information, try again
and find out mistakes please""")
    time.sleep(10)
```

*Further only display the contents of the functions on the screen*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "it always failed" ? What kind of error/misbehaviour did you get?

By the way, your exception catching code is wrong (as it actually instantiates an exception!). Try this:

```
import pyowm
from pyowm.exceptions import api_response_error
try:
    owm.weather_at_place(place)
except api_response_error.NotFoundError:
    print('Wrong information, try again and find out mistakes please')
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just announced variable "main" in try-catch cycle and code is working now. Thanks for attention and help everyone!